# Swapping <div> in a continous JQuery loop

Tags: jquery

I am working on having a single div animate right to left through the header. Once the div goes off screen and finishes animation I would like to loop the animation but swap the div for another containing a new image. The code is below but not functioning properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var clouds = $('#bg_header .cloud');
       var lng = clouds.length;
    $('.cloud').eq(0).animate({
        right: '+=1400'
        }, 50000, 'linear', anim(1));
          function anim(i) {
          if (i >= lng) {
          i = 0;
     }
    $('.cloud').eq(i).animate({
        right: '+=1400'
        }, 50000, 'linear', anim(i+1));
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="bg_header">
<div id="clouds" class="cloud" style="right:-400px;"><img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="/images/clouds.png" /></div>
<div id="clouds2" class="cloud" style="right:-400px;"><img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="/images/clouds2.png" /></div>
```

CSS

```
#bg_header{
min-width:990px;
padding-left:105px;
padding-right:105px;
right:0;
left:0;
height:330px;
position:fixed;
background:url("/images/bg_header.png") repeat-x top center;
z-index:1000;
clear:both;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}


#clouds{
position:absolute;
z-index:500;
right:0px;
top:10px;
}


#clouds2{
position:absolute;
z-index:500;
right:0px;
top:10px;
}
```

Comment: So you want to have 2 clouds on your header: 1 of it moving from right to left ,then when the first one disappears the second one should start animating from right to left and so on.Right?

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for. I also would like to have the option to add more clouds so not limited to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say precisely what the problem is (just that it's not "functioning properly") but one obvious problem is your callback reference to `animate()` is executed immediately rather than passed as a function reference.

Change

```
$('.cloud').eq(0).animate({
    right: '+=1400'
}, 50000, 'linear', anim(1));
```

to

```
$('.cloud').eq(0).animate({
    right: '+=1400'
}, 50000, 'linear', function() { anim(1); });
```

Comment: After editing the script the animation abruptly stops 3/4 through with error; 
Script: resource://firebug/firebug-service.js:4218

Comment: Clearly I can't tell anything from that error, but the point remains - you want your call to `anim(1)` to happen *after* the initial animation, not at the same time as it (which is what your original code had, as you were calling the function, not passing a reference to it).